# Can I find my most played songs on Google Play Music?

Tags: google-music

In iTunes, we have the "Top 25 Most Played" default playlist.  I am wondering if there is something similar in Google Play.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

On desktop, you can go to Music Library, Songs, then click the music note to see songs you've played the most. However, this will only show songs in your library, i.e. songs you have downloaded to a device. I have looked all over and don't think there's a way to do exactly what you want.

Comment: Yea...   Music Library covers at least my own music + what I've downloaded.   Would love something across all songs.

Comment: I've found a better way to do this, assuming you "thumbs up" songs you like, is to go to your Thumbs Up playlist and sort by most liked. That way you get songs you have both on and off your device. Of course, this won't work if you don't thumb up songs. Also, I'm not sure it accounts for songs listened to on other devices.